# node/angular2 services returning values to wrong component

Tags: node.js, angular2-services

I am new to nodejs/angular2. I am having a strange issue with Async behavior of node and its return to an angular service. The issue I am having is two different angular components say component A and component B have the same angular service injected in them.

The server side is an async node server which takes some time to complete the request.The problem is when the app routes from angular component A to angular component B, sometimes the request to node completes from component A but since we are currently routed to component B the response goes there. 
 (Component A and B are not visible at the same time. Only one is visible at a time)

Because component B is also subscribed to the same service/method it will get the return result that was designated for component A. Resulting in incorrect values.

Is there a way from Component B to only receive the responses to the requests it sent out.

Both are components are subscribed to the same method within the service as such:

The code is way to big to put on here so I am going to do snippets.

Here is the code that is in each component.

```
getNode(){

    this.userService.getNode().subscribe(resNodeData => {
    this.node = resNodeData; 
            if(this.node == null){
            return null;
        }
        else{
     // console.log(this.node);  
            }
        });
```

}

Code from Service Layer:

```
export class UserService {
  //call to node server async
 getNode() {
return this.http.get("http://" + host + ":3000/api/namenode/"  + this.clusterService.getCluster())
.map((res:Response) => res.json())
.catch(this._errorHandler);
  }


 }
```

I know my question is long and confusing. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to unsubscribe in the lifecycle hook OnDestroy for both components.

Comment: No the payload coming from the node server will still get delivered to the component that is now subscribed to the service layer. I tried this and it will not work. I have left this in the codebase regardless.

Comment: Dang, I'll see if I can recreate this tomorrow. In the meantime, what version of Angular are you using? Did you create the project with angular-cli, and if not then what are you using?

Comment: I am using angular 2.4.10. I am also using angular-cli 1.3.0. I think what I will need to do is use the onDestroy method as you suggested and use a framework like bluebird to send some sort of cancellation request to the node server, such that it does not send the payload to the next component observing from this service. Either that or I will need to break the abstraction and just use a different method name called in the service layer by two different components. ( I would hate to do this)

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you are not using Angular 4?

Comment: I am working in a codebase that I did not create but for a company I work for. They selected the stack. Does angular 4 have a way to cancel the request?

Comment: Hey! Sorry I totally forgot about this. I tried to recreate the issue but I couldn't